# Checkbox -cross out the text when clicking checkBox for a todo list

Tags: javascript, checkbox

I've been watching a tutorial on how to cross out the text when clicking on the `checkbox` next to the text and my code doesn't work, even though its the same as one in the tutorial (where it works just fine).
I've been looking at my code for so long but can't see whats wrong, maybe its just a typo I can't see… anyone knows why?

Here is the JavaScript code (just the relevant part)

```
function updatingItem() {

  var cbId = this.id.replace("cb_", "");
  var textItem = document.getElementById("item_" + cbId);
  textItem.style.textDecoration = "line-through";
}

function addItem() {

  totalItems++;
  var entry = document.createElement("li");
  var checkBox = document.createElement("input");
  checkBox.type = "checkbox";
  checkBox.id = "cb_" + totalItems;
  checkBox.onclick = updatingItem;

  var span = document.createElement("span");
  span.id = "item_" + totalItems;
  span.innerHtml = textItem;

  var textItem = document.getElementById("textItem");
  entry.innerText = textItem.value;
  var location = document.getElementById("todoList");

  entry.appendChild(checkBox);
  entry.appendChild(span);
  location.appendChild(entry);
}
```

Comment: You should really create / show a minimal but complete code that reflects your issue.

Comment: Where is your `totalItems` variable defined?

Comment: You main issue is that you have `span.innerHtml = textItem;` set before actually getting the value  `var textItem = document.getElementById("textItem");`

Answer (score 3):

You main issue is that you have `span.innerHtml = textItem;` set before actually getting the value `var textItem = document.getElementById("textItem");`

But hey...

**CSS only**:

```css
label{
  display: block;
}
label input[type=checkbox]:checked + span{
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

```html
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox">
    <span>Buy Coffee</span>
  </label>
  
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" checked>
    <span>Ask question on SO</span>
  </label>
  
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox">
    <span>Drink coffee</span>
  </label>
```

And here's a **much simpler** trivial *not-quite-a-tutorial* self-explanatory JS code:

```js
var todoList = document.getElementById("todoList");
var itemText = document.getElementById("itemText");
var add      = document.getElementById("add");

add.addEventListener("click", function(){

  var text = itemText.value.trim();

  // IF NO TEXT ENTERED - DO NOTHING
  if(!text.length) return ;

  // CREATE AND APPEND HTML
  var item = "<li><label><input type='checkbox'> <span>"+ text+"</span></label></li>";
  todoList.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', item);

  // FINALLY CLEAR THE TEXT FROM OUR INPUT
  itemText.value = ""; 
  
});
```

```css
label{
  display: block;
}
label input[type=checkbox]:checked + span{
  text-decoration: line-through;
  background:rgba(0,255,0, 0.2);
}
```

```html
<ul id="todoList">
  <li>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox">
      <span>Buy Coffee</span>
    </label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" checked>
      <span>Ask question on SO</span>
    </label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox">
      <span>Drink coffee</span>
    </label>
  </li>
</ul>

<input id="itemText" type="text">
<button id="add">ADD TO LIST</button>
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

Comment: you are using css on text you already have created (Buy coffee, Ask question etc) but I am not creating any text in my html file-its a todo list so the content is being created by typing in something, then when clicking the checkbox it should be crossed off.

Comment: @learningcoding I did not sayed you should not use JS for the `ADD TODO ITEM` part, I'm just saying that you can cross your items using CSS alone.

Comment: @learningcoding expanded my answer. Hopefully will shade some light.

Comment: I really just wanted to know what was wrong in my code so I understand what i did wrong

Comment: @learningcoding JS is mostly about DOM manipulation, you showed in your question only the JS. You should show a minimal and verifiable code snippet, that means adding some HTML, and CSS (if relevant for presentation).

Comment: @learningcoding Explained what you did wrong + added the elements and IDs that, I guess, reflect pretty well your current HTML structure.

Answer (score 0):

A little inspection tells me your text is not being added to your `span` but rather to the entry itself

So here's my replication of your problem

```js
var totalItems = 0;

function updatingItem() {
  var cbId = this.id.replace("cb_", "");
  var textItem = document.getElementById("item_" + cbId);
  textItem.style.textDecoration = "line-through";
}

function addItem() {
  totalItems++;
  var entry = document.createElement("li");
  var checkBox = document.createElement("input");
  checkBox.type = "checkbox";
  checkBox.id = "cb_" + totalItems;
  checkBox.onclick = updatingItem;

  var span = document.createElement("span");
  span.id = "item_" + totalItems;
  span.innerHtml = textItem;

  var textItem = document.getElementById("textItem");
  entry.innerText = textItem.value;          //<<<<<Problem is here
  var location = document.getElementById("todoList");

  entry.appendChild(checkBox);
  entry.appendChild(span);
  location.appendChild(entry);
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <ol id="todoList">
    </ol>
    <input type="text" id="textItem" placeholder="blabla"/>
    <button onclick="addItem()">add item</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

A slight modification that fixes your problem

```js
var totalItems = 0;

function updatingItem() {
  var cbId = this.id.replace("cb_", "");
  var textItem = document.getElementById("item_" + cbId);
  textItem.style.textDecoration = "line-through";
}

function addItem() {
  totalItems++;
  var entry = document.createElement("li");
  var checkBox = document.createElement("input");
  checkBox.type = "checkbox";
  checkBox.id = "cb_" + totalItems;
  checkBox.onclick = updatingItem;

  var span = document.createElement("span");
  span.id = "item_" + totalItems;
  //span.innerHtml = textItem;             <<<<<Comment this out

  var textItem = document.getElementById("textItem");
  span.innerText = textItem.value;          //<<<<<Changed entry to span
  var location = document.getElementById("todoList");

  entry.appendChild(checkBox);
  entry.appendChild(span);
  location.appendChild(entry);
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <ol id="todoList">
    </ol>
    <input type="text" id="textItem" placeholder="blabla"/>
    <button onclick="addItem()">add item</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks! It works now. The only thin is, since I changed it to span.innerText = textItem.value; the text moved to the right -before it was right next to/after the check box and now it moved much away to the right..

Comment: Regarding moving-to-the-right problem, I think you may need to look at the styling of the span in particular position, text-align, and float. By the way, It's always a better practice to toggle css classes instead of setting inline styles.